# Datetimefield argument

Tags: django

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

This is from the Django official tutorial. `models.DateTimeField('date published')` Why is there a string as argument? According to the docs, it seems that DateTimeField does not accept string argument. Thank you for your help.

Comment: this is the `Field` signature, from which every field inherit `def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, ...`)

Comment: @pritamsamanta, it is from here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/

Answer (score 3):

**Each field type**, except for ForeignKey, ManyToManyField and OneToOneField, **takes an optional first positional argument – a verbose name.** If the verbose name isn’t given, Django will automatically create it using the field’s attribute name, converting underscores to spaces. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names)

```
class DateTimeField(DateField):
......
class DateField(DateTimeCheckMixin, Field):
....
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, auto_now=False,
                 auto_now_add=False, **kwargs):
```

you can see DateTimeField class implementation in detail [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/__init__.py).